# How open source projects work without project manager?

Tags: project-management-style, open-source

Somebody told me the open source projects go ahead without project managers and it was interesting for me to know is this really true? If so, how does it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open-source projects are often associated with agile methodologies, but you shouldn't confuse the 2 concepts.

The agile manifesto calls upon self-organising teams - in that sense, there is no project manager in the traditional sense.

There are 3 roles in scrum

1. the product owner - essentially the stakeholder's advocate
2. the scrum master: providing methodology and structure, but not deciding on the contents. The scrum master can also act as a moderator, facilator and coach.
3. the team members: there is no leader, the team is supposed to
   be self-organising.

Comment: Your post does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Open-Source projects [most of the time] always have a leader! The leader manages all code submissions and decides which ones to add to the software!

I would like to bring to your attention **LINUX** which was a revolution at the time. But it was **Linus Torvalds** who managed everything! The leader is the guy in charge of a project, but has zero hiring and firing authority.

For an open-source project to work out, you should have a set of rules to stick by. For example:

- Do whatever it takes to make people feel welcome so that they continue working with you.
- Code of Conduct - provides an interesting point you can refer to as soon as you need to.
- Vision is necessary - No vision, no future!
- Be Thankful - recognize contributions.
- Ship, Ship, Ship - don't try to build the perfect infrastructure!